# Factorization of a polynomial without real root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $q(x)=ax^n+bx^{n-1}+...+c $ be a polynomial without root in $\mathbb{R}$. Does it mean that there is no factorization of $q(x)$?

Comment: How about $1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 2 x^3 + x^4=(x^2+x+1)(x^2+x+1)$?

Comment: It is true iff $n \le 3$

Comment: you can find some polynomials that have no real roots and after that by multiplying these polynomials we have a counterexample for your claim such as the first comment.

Comment: @Amin235 this shows logically that such polynomials just can not exist without coming with an explicit example. Nice!

Comment: Any real polynomial can be factored over $\mathbb{R}$ as a product of linear factors and quadratic factors with negative discriminant, see [irreducible polynomials over the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial#Over_the_reals) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, complex roots exist in the system of complex numbers, conditions are: degree of polynomial $ ≥3 $

Consider the following example.

$z^3 = 1$
$ \implies z =(1)^{\frac{1}{3}} $ has only one real root i.e. $1$ , the two other cube roots of unity are complex.

Which are found using $ z^3-1 = (z-1)(z^2+z+1) $

So, we can factorise to get $ \frac{-1±i√3}{2} $ as other two root

However you can consider $ 1+2x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4=(x^2+x+1)(x^2+x+1) $ which has no roots in real no. system